# Getting user array through api

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get user values from the database through my api. I'm able to get all the users using the first code example but when i try to get a specific users values I'm not able to then using the second example.

I'm guessing the problem is with the ng-repeat but i don't know how to fix it.

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in management.users | filter: searchFilter | limitTo: management.limit">
            <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.email }}</td>
        </tr>
```

```
router.get('/management', function(req, res) {
    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
        // Some code 
        res.json({ success: true, users: users, permission: mainUser.permission });
        // Return users, along with current user's permission

    });
});
```

---

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in edit.user | filter: searchFilter | limitTo: management.limit">
            <td>{{ person.test1 }}</td>
        </tr>
```

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
    var editUser = req.params.id; // Assign the _id from parameters to variable
    User.findOne({ username: req.decoded.username }, function(err, mainUser) {
      // Some code 
      res.json({ success: true, user: user }); 
      // Return the user to be editted

    });
```

Comment: Nothing to repeat over if you only have one user object

Comment: whats the response of your user.findone api, is an array?, remember ng-rpeat is for itarate arrays. Check the reponse of the api maybe is an object.